# Xamarin forms Listview - UI does not update when ObservableRangeCollection is updated

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a listview with several data templates. One of the templates is simple textbox and button for barcode scan (ZXingLibrary). The page with listview is displayed modally. The page displays a question with the list of responses bound to the listview. Barcode type template is one such response.

I am updating the observable range collection bound to the listview in the following code. This function is called after successful barcode scan.

```
private void UpdateUserResponseList(UserResponse obs, string result)
    {
        var temp = obs;
        obs.RValue = result;
        ObsList.Remove(temp);
        ObsList.Add(obs);
     }
```

When the UI refreshes the indexes of the listitem changes in both platforms. This works perfectly in iOS. But in Android, the UI is refreshed only when the count of ObsList is greater than 1. It saves the value in the collection, but does not appear/update in the textbox.

**ListView**

```
 <ListView x:Name="ObsListView" IsVisible="{Binding IsObservations}" CachingStrategy="RecycleElement" Margin="20" ItemsSource="{Binding ObsList}" SeparatorVisibility="None" HasUnevenRows="true" BackgroundColor="Transparent" 
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ObservationDataEntrySelector}" />
```

**ObservableRangeCollection**

```
public ObservableRangeCollection<UserResponse> ObsList 
{ 
     get 
       { return _obsList; } 
     set 
       { 
          if (_obsList != value) 
          { 
             _obsList = value; 
             OnPropertyChanged("ObsList"); } } 
       }
 }
```

**Function called when the user clicks *Scan Barcode* button**

```
private void BarcodeScannerExecuted(UserResponse obj)
    {
        ZXingScannerPage scanPage = new ZXingScannerPage();
        var customOverlay = new StackLayout
        {
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand

        };

        var Cancel_Button = new Button
        {
            Text = "Cancel",
            Command = CancelScanningCommand,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,

        };

        var Text_shown = new Label
        {
            Text = "Hold your device up to the barcode,Scanning will happen automatically",
            TextColor = Xamarin.Forms.Color.DarkRed,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand

        };

        customOverlay.Children.Add(Cancel_Button);
        customOverlay.Children.Add(Text_shown);
        scanPage = new ZXingScannerPage(customOverlay: customOverlay);
        scanPage.OnScanResult += (result) =>
        {
            scanPage.IsScanning = false;
            Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
            {
                UpdateUserResponseList(obj, result.Text);
                await _navigation.NavigatePopModalAsync();
            });
        };
        _navigation.NavigatePushModalAsync(scanPage);
    }
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and show us how are you calling this method. First thought that I am getting is maybe you are not calling it from a Main UI Thread.

Comment: @AlmirVuk  thank you for responding. I have added the code from where this method is called. I have tried several other things over the week, no resolution yet :(